# How detach my custom widget from Qt QWidgetList?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5

I have a container `std::map<std::string, unique_ptr<ItemWidget>> widgets` that contains pointers to my widgets, so all of my widgets exist separately and independend from `QListWidget` object. Sometimes i need to hide some of widgets temporarily, sometimes to delete ones finally. So my code implements this:

```
ui->listWidget->clear()
for (auto it : widgets) {
    auto item = new QListWidgetItem();
    item->setSizeHint(it->size());
    ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
    ui->listWidget->setItemWidget(item, it);
}
```

Now i read that `ui->listWidget->clear()` calls `delete` for all list's items. And thats why my list has all items with no data.

I want to list to delete my widgets from itself, but without any impact to my widgets. Can i?

UDPATE. This is not about `clear`. Function that deletes my CustomWidget is probably `setItemWidget`. I am not so sure, but problem is definitly that some class, function or else deletes my ItemWidget

Comment: It looks like your code makes a copy of the `unique_ptr`? That is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: `clear` only calls delete on the `QListWidgetItem` object. Not your `ItemWidget` object.

Comment: @Botje You right, but this is not exactly the same code as i have in my project In real code there is `get()` called from `unique_ptr`.

Comment: That is the same problem. You have a "unique_ptr" *and* a place in Qt pointing towards the same memory location. Thereby it is not a unique_ptr. Using `get()` is only for lending a pointer to APIs that do not support unique pointers and do not take ownership.

Comment: @Botje Yes, but `ui->listWidget->setItemWidget` does not take ownership, isnt it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're trying to do.  Aren't you just looking for something like [`QListWidget::removeItemWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlistwidget.html#removeItemWidget)?

Comment: @G.M. Hello. I wrote this in update. Thing is this code works normally. I held `QMessageBox` in `ItemWidget` destructor, so i saw that before destructor was called all my new widgets succesfully redrawed. But after, something in Qt (because of call stack) was calling `ItemWidget` destructor, for no reason)

Comment: @G.M. And if i comment `setItemWidget()`, obviously nothing will be drawed, but ALSO no call for `ItemWidget` destructor. That's why i think that `setItemWidget()` doing something wrong with my pointer in this context

Comment: If you really have `std::map<std::string, unique_ptr<ItemWidget>> widgets`, then `for (auto it : widgets)` [wouldn't have compiled](https://godbolt.org/z/shrnb9zf7). What code are you actually running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you even guard `QWidget` by `unique_ptr`? They aren't meant to. They are stored in global repository, registered in event queue , are owned by parent widgets.

You can't even safely delete widget from inside of running event loop. You have to use `QObject::deleteLater()` instead of `delete` on them or you have a case of UB.

`unique_ptr` is not copyable so code above really claims to cause disaster. And `QListWidget` is Qt-friendly analog of " container of smart unowning pointers".

Qt got "weak pointer class" for `QObjects`. It's `QPointer`. It clears itself if it pointed at `QObject` instance and that got deleted from framework.

So, it sounds like you need to use `QList<QWidget*>` or `QList<QPointer<QWidget*>>` in your case. And `QMap`. And it got own owning smart pointer `QSharedPointer`. And no C++ smart pointers, framework is not designed to be used with them or you have be careful with deleters.